# Python Local Package Doesn't Load In Call From PHP

Tags: php, python, linux

So, I want to run a Python program with a home-directory install of PyProj from PHP. The PHP and Python are simple, but I include them below for completeness.

I've tested running Python manually using both `sys.path.append` and `PYTHONPATH` to specify the location of the package. Both of these methods work.

However, when I `shell_exec` the script from PHP, I'm told `ImportError: No module named pyproj`.

A recursive check of the file system reveals that everything is read/executable by user, group, and other.

Any thoughts on why this I can't get this to run?

I'm calling it in a PHP script as follows

```
<?php
        putenv('PYTHONPATH="/home/userperson/public_html/lib64/python2.4/site-packages"');
        $ret=shell_exec("./bob");
        print $ret;
?>
```

The Python program is simple.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pyproj
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/userperson/public_html/lib64/python2.4/site-packages")
surfproj = pyproj.Proj(proj='lcc',lat_1=40,lat_2=50,lon_0=-95,lat_0=40,ellps='WGS84')
x,y=surjproj(-95,45)
print x
```

Comment: What happens if you `import sys` first, then `print sys.path`? Does the output include the directory that contains your module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to solve a problem like this is to print the `sys.path` from a Python script in this environment and check what the current path is:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 import sys
 print sys.path
```

My guess is that it will containt `'"/home/userperson/public_html/lib64/python2.4/site-packages"'` (note the superfluous double quotes).

The documentation of `putenv($setting)` doesn't say anything about supporting shell syntax, quotes or escaping inside the setting, so any characters present in the strings would no doubt end in the value of the environmental variable. A possible fix for the issue would be:

```
putenv('PYTHONPATH=/home/userperson/public_html/lib64/python2.4/site-packages');
```

Another useful hint would be to put the path in a separate variable, and just do `putenv("PYTHONPATH=$pythonpath")` or `putenv("PYTHONPATH=" . implode(':', $pythonpath))`, as this would allow you to check if the paths exist from your PHP script with `file_exists`.

Older versions of PHP might have issue if `safe_mode` is enabled and `PYTHONPATH` isn't in the `safe_mode_allowed_env_vars`, but hopefully you're not running on a server configured like that.

Comment: Good call. There were superfluous quote marks in the path, so that's working using putenv now. Thanks!